# Are there other usages of a protocol other than a delegate?

Tags: objective-c

I was just wondering are there other usages of a protocol other than a delegate?  I've only seen protocol's been used as delegates but I haven't noticed if it has any other purpose.  So are there actual purposes of protocol's other than a delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the apple docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html

Protocols declare methods that can be implemented by any class. Protocols are useful in at least three situations:

- To declare methods that others are expected to implement
- To declare the interface to an object while concealing its class
- To capture similarities among classes that are not hierarchically related

Specifically, as an example, I've also used protocols to implement a provider model where I abstract out complete parts of the system.  For example, to decouple my code a bit more, I could create a data provider.  I could have a sqlite provider, a file provider etc...  A protocol allows me to decouple those.

In that case, each of the providers do not inherit from each other but they all implement the same pattern with the internals being different.  Think of a protocol as a pattern you conform to - or, a contract if you think of it like an interface.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You would use it anywhere you want to define a set of shared behavior without imposing a particular inheritance tree.